# parseInt output wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]
`console.log(parseInt("110000111010000011100101010001010101000100000000000000000001111", 2));`
The output result was wrong, even it is in google browser console.
The correct output is 7048259459772055567

I think the number is too big so nodejs cannot solve it?

Comment: `7048259459772055567` is above `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Above this numbers are imprecise.

Comment: You should use BigInt instead of parseInt because it is such a long string you are passing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, that number is much larger than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), so it cannot be accurately represented. You can use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt)s to work with numbers of this scale.

```js
let str = "110000111010000011100101010001010101000100000000000000000001111";
let n = BigInt('0b' + str);
console.log('' + n);
```